# Use of "いかん" in the following sentences

Tags: grammar

とは思うのだが、口に出すわけにもいかんか。My personal translations would be these: Those are my thoughts on that (previous statement), so I might as well say it out loud.

and

出動後はそうはいかんぞ。。。 "but after they move out, how it goes..."

I'm not sure how "いかん" works. Dictionnary says it means: how, in what way.
Or is it an abbreviation of "いかない", or even "いけない" or something else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the first sentence: https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n3-grammar-%E3%82%8F%E3%81%91%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-wake-niwa-ikanai/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

いかん is basically an alternative form of いかない and いけない (used in some dialects especially in the 関西).

わけにもいかん comes from the grammar わけにはいかない, and it means something like "(I) cannot afford to... either".

> とは思うのだが、口に出すわけにもいかんか。: I think so, but can't (I) afford to even say it out loud?

In the second sentence however, it would mean いけない (which means something like 良くない).

Comment: 「出動後はそうはいかんぞ」の 「いかん」が、"(things) won't go (that way, so smoothly)" でなく "良くない" という意味だということでしょうか。