# Verb-past + にゃいかん

Tags: grammar, contractions

> 最高の杖を持たにゃいかん。
> You've got to have the best wand.

The meaning is clear, but I'm baffled by the grammar.

First, I'm assuming 持た is a typo for 持った, but maybe not?

Second, I'm guessing that にゃいかん is a contraction of にはいかない. But the only grammar I know involving にはいかない is **わけ**にはいかない and that would give the opposite meaning to my translation. I cannot find verb-past + にはいかない in any reference.

I know the character talks with a heavy dialect in the original book (Hagrid from Harry Potter) but I can normally see how what he says is connected to standard grammar. This one has me stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a correct sentence. The sentence is the same as 最高の杖を持たないといけない but said in stereotypical "(wise) old man speech".

- 持たにゃ is short for 持たねば ([eba-to-ya contraction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12580/5010)).
- 持たねば is a literary/classical form of 持たないと

  - [ねば in 食べねば; relation between ねば and なければ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3061/5010)
  - [What verb form is くださねばなるまい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55706/5010)
- いかん is a dialectal/old way of saying いけない

  - [Use of "いかん" in the following sentences](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61398/5010)
  - [Weird Inflection -されていかん](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65681/5010)